# __NSDictionaryM was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to set all keys from my NSMutableDictionary as 0, but I'm getting the following error:

`__NSDictionaryM was mutated while being enumerated`

There's my code:

```
 -(void)marcarTodosRoteiros {
    _numeroRoteirosSelecionados = (int)[self.roteirosSelecionados count];
    for(id key in self.roteirosSelecionados) {
        [self.roteirosSelecionados setObject:@"1" forKey:key];
    }
    [self.tbFiltros reloadData];
}
```

Comment: this is one of the cases where reading the error message actually tells you EVERYTHING you need to know  - you mutate a NSDictionary while enumerating it - solution: **dont mutate a NSDictionary while enumerating it**

Answer (score 4):

This is the enumeration:

```
for(id key in self.roteirosSelecionados)
```

and this is the mutation:

```
    [self.roteirosSelecionados setObject:@"1" forKey:key];
```

You cannot do that.  What you should do in this case is get all the keys into a separate array and then set `@"1"` for each key:

```
-(void)marcarTodosRoteiros {
    NSArray *keys = [self.roteirosSelecionados allKeys];
    for (NSString *key in keys)
        [self.roteirosSelecionados setObject:@"1" forKey:key];
    [self.tbFiltros reloadData];
}
```